# Is there any relation of measure theory and function space, with B-Spline(Basis-spline) and cubic spline?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Actually I am a M.Sc. thesis student in Mathematics(Pure Mathematics) and doing my thesis on function space and measure  but I have also studied  about B-Spline and and cubic spline . But the problem is that if I want to insert the topics B-spline and cubic spline then I have to show that B-spline, cubic spline function space and measure theory  are related in somehow otherwise in my thesis presentation and viva I will face a great problem from the viva board members. That is why I need a good and reasonable relation to insert the topics B-spline in my M.Sc. thesis paper. I want to go abroad for higher education and want to apply my mathematical knowledge in real world  problem  . That is why I want to solve the partial differential  equation and differential equation using B-spline.   **I have also learnt about banach space,hilbert space.**

Answer (score 1):

Spline spaces are finite dimensional vector spaces. A lot of CAD work with splines is actually just fiddling around with different bases of spline spaces, and with dual bases.

Bezier curves are even simpler -- they are just polynomials, and vector spaces of polynomials have many interesting bases: Bernstein, Lagrange, Chebyshev, Laguerre, etc.

Many applications of splines are approximation problems. As you probably know, approximating a function $f$ by a spline can often be regarded as finding the closest point to $f$ that lies in some linear subspace of some spline space. You get different answers depending on what norm you use in the function space -- the $L_2$ norm gives you least-squares approximations, the uniform norm gives you minimax approximation, etc.

For more info look at the book "A Practical Guide to Splines" by Carl de Boor.

I don't know of any connections with measure theory.